# JSF 2 : dataTable columnClasses is not replicated after 2 columns

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Im using glassfish 3.0.1 and was experimenting with columnClasses in dataTable for the first time.

It's something like this :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{coreGridBean.heroBeanList}" var="hero"
                    captionStyle="font-size: 0.95em; font-style:italic"
                    styleClass="orders"
                    headerClass="ordersHeader"
                    footerClass="ordersHeader"
                    columnClasses="oddColumn,evenColumn">
```

From the core jsf book im reading, it says that by specifying only 2 classes in the columnClasses attribute, those 2 will be repeated when the column amount is more than 2.

Let's say that i have five columns, the columnClasses would become something like oddColumn,evenColumn,oddColumn,evenColumn,oddColumn, and we just need to define it like this : columnClasses="oddColumn,evenColumn"

But in my experience with 3 columns, it's not like this. From the third column they got no classes. I had to specify columnClasses="oddColumn,evenColumn,oddColumn" to make it work

Is this a bug or i just have a bad error ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The repetition only applies on `rowClasses`.

From the [JSF 2.0 `h:dataTable` tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html):

> ### columnClasses
>
> Comma-delimited list of CSS style classes that will be applied to the columns of this table. A space separated list of classes may also be specified for any individual column. **If the number of elements in this list is less than the number of actual column children of the UIData, no "class" attribute is output for each column greater than the number of elements in the list.** If the number of elements in the list is greater than the number of actual column children of the UIData, the elements at the posisiton in the list after the last column are ignored.
>
> ---
>
> ### rowClasses
>
> Comma-delimited list of CSS style classes that will be applied to the rows of this table. A space separated list of classes may also be specified for any individual row. Thes styles are applied, in turn, to each row in the table. For example, if the list has two elements, the first style class in the list is applied to the first row, the second to the second row, the first to the third row, the second to the fourth row, etc. **In other words, we keep iterating through the list until we reach the end, and then we start at the beginning again.**

Maybe the book was wrong, or you misread the book.

Since the column number is usually always fixed in the view definition anyway, it's little effort to just repeat them yourself.

```
<h:dataTable columnClasses="oddColumn,evenColumn,oddColumn,evenColumn">
    <h:column></h:column>
    <h:column></h:column>
    <h:column></h:column>
    <h:column></h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: After reading your answer, i also thought i was misreading the book, but here's a sentence from the book : We specified only two column classes, but notice that we have five columns.
In this case, h:dataTable reuses the column classes, starting with the first. By
specifying only the first two column classes, we can set the CSS classes for odd
and even columns. (When using the terms odd and even in this way, we assume
that the first column is column 1.) ..

Comment: And also another sentence from the book : 
and another sentence : Like column classes, h:dataTable reuses row classes when the number of classes
is less than the number of rows. In the preceding code fragment, we have taken
advantage of this feature to specify CSS classes for odd and even rows.

Comment: Is it the Core JSF 2.0 book edition 3? Anyway, I sent them an email about the mistake.

Comment: Yeap, that book, only the 3rd edition talks about JSF version 2.0, and if im not mistaken only JSF 2 that has dataTable ? I already posted an errata on corejsf.com..

Comment: @BalusC in the JSF complete reference 2.0 thay made the same mistake when talking about panelGrid "A comma-separated list of CSS classes to be associated with the rendered columns. The classes will be applied in a repeating fashion to all columns in the panelGrid component."